# System dbs have different collation

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, collation, system-databases

i am new on this forum.i have installed an instance of sql srv 2016 sp2 called DNF containing 2 dbs and also the system dbs.after providing the instance to the dev team the realise that they need to change the collation.they changed the collation for the 2 dbs by themselves and ask me to make the change for the system dbs.i took a backup of all databases and rebuild the system dbs. It works fine and all the dbs changed to new  collation.
I made a mistake by restoring the msdb, model and finally i tried to restore the master. I succeeded to restore the model and msdb and faced a lot issue when coming to master. I ran the query select name, collation_name from sys.databases and found that the model and msdb have the old collation, and this is logic and was a mistake from me.
I tried to rebuild again, but collation refuse to change on model and msdb and found the sql server and sql server for the instance stopped and won't to start anymore.
The situation now is : master and the 2 non system dbs have the new collation and model,msdb have the old one, and the services won't start.
What is the way to solve this issue? Does an instance repair will solve this issue? Or there is something else that i can do?
Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: You have backups of all databases before making the collation changes? Would you lose any data by restoring those backups, or you can restore them?

Comment: Yes i have a backup. I successfuly repaired the instance few minutes ago and the services start successfuly and i have the chance to access the instance again. I tried to rebuild the system databases again using the command provided by MS setup /QUIET /ACTION= REBUILDDATABASE etc... the command return no error, but still model,msdb,temp have different collation from master.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are restoring the original `model` and `msdb` databases which retain their initial collation. The collation of those two databases (and hence `tempdb` which is built from `model` each time the instance starts up) is not going to change simply by restoring them to an instance that has a different collation. You have two options:

1. The quickest / easiest / safest option is to *not* restore the `model` and `msdb` databases. Do you really need them?

   - The `model` DB is the template used to create new DBs (including `tempdb`) and is *typically* not customized / modified. Assuming no changes were ever made to `model` (which is the case 99% of the time), then there is absolutely no use in restoring it — it's extra work for no gain. And, if by chance there is custom configuration done in `model`, it should be easy enough to repeat those steps in the rebuilt instance.
   - The `msdb` DB contains Database Backup history, configuration for various subsystems such as SQL Agent, Log Shipping, Database Mail, SSIS Packages, Registered Servers (if I remember correctly), etc, among other things. Do you have a lot of data / configuration for any subsystems? If this is a new instance then I would expect that there is probably very little data here. In this case you can probably ignore history data (and if this is a DEV box, does it really matter?).
     So, rather than restoring `msdb` (which isn't working anyway), simply migrate over any configuration (SQL Agent jobs / alerts / schedules / etc, Mail server / profiles / etc, and so on). Those should be easy enough to script out via SQL Server Management Studio (even better would be any configuration was already scripted out and possibly stored in source control  and can just be re-applied to the rebuilt instance).
2. If you have *A LOT* of data / configuration in `msdb`, or if you know that customization has been done but nobody can tell you what they configured (certainly not a situation that inspires confidence in successful future deployment), then you can use the undocumented method to change the collation of existing DBs. I have written an article about it here:

   [Changing the Collation of the SQL Server Instance, the Databases, and All Columns in All User Databases: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/06/11/changing-the-collation-of-the-instance-and-all-columns-across-all-user-databases-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/)

   To be as safe as possible, if you do use this method, I would suggest detaching your two non-system DBs first, then use this method to update the collation of the instance, and then reattach the two non-system DBs (since they are already at the desired collation and don't need to be updated). Please note that this method will not update anything if the instance-level collation is already set to the target/new collation.